# Shouldn't recursion take twice as many time as loop?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, time-complexity

what is the time complexity of this example about linked list:

```
void Display(Node* p) {
   if (p != nullptr) {
       Display(p->next);
       std::cout << p->data;
   }
}
```

because we are calling the function n times (number of elements) the complexity should be O(n)? but what happens when Display returns? doesn't it take another n- times to complete printing operation?

Comment: Re-read your course notes on the exact definition of big-oh notation. Constants and constant multipliers are ignored so O(n) == O(2n) === O(3n) etc.

Comment: Also note: Most people don't print their lists in reverse order and `void Display(Node* p) { if (p != nullptr) { std::cout << p->data; Display(p->next); }` will use *tail recursion* in most compilers and never return from the Display calls one by one. The last call returns straight to the first caller. So be careful when counting costs, the optimizer might avoid them.

Comment: Please show the loop that you believe does half the work.

Comment: To complement the comment by @Botje - ask yourself **why** constant multipliers are ignored - it has to do with growth rates, which big o is all about.

Comment: Yes recursion can do more work then a loop, (call + std::cout +return) but O is about how often it makes those steps. Not how long those steps take (if they do not depend on input size).

Comment: Time complexity is about how the execution time increases when the size of the data increases. If you double the amount of data (e.g., double the number of elements in the list), the code executes twice as many steps. That's O(n), regardless of how many steps are required for one data element. One approach could well take twice as long as another on the same size data, but as long as they scale the same way when you increase the amount of data, they have the same time complexity.